# Get first and nth non-blank value per row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following input dataframe:

```
              0     1     2     3    4
date                                  
2007-02-15  NaN -0.88  0.80   NaN  0.5
2007-02-16  0.5 -0.84   NaN  0.29  NaN
2007-02-19  NaN -0.84  0.79  0.29  NaN
2007-02-20  0.5  0.50  0.67  0.20  0.5
```

I need to get an output dataframe with the first and the nth (for example, third) non-blank value for each row. This is the expected output:

```
             1st   3rd
date                  
2007-02-15 -0.88  0.50
2007-02-16  0.50  0.29
2007-02-19 -0.84  0.29
2007-02-20  0.50  0.67
```

For the first value, I know I can do the following:

```
df2['1st'] = df.fillna(method='bfill', axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

but what can I do to find the 3rd one? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### 1rst and 3rd

```
g = df.stack().groupby(level=0)

out = pd.concat({'1st': g.first(), '3rd': g.nth(2)}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
             1st   3rd
date                  
2007-02-15 -0.88  0.50
2007-02-16  0.50  0.29
2007-02-19 -0.84  0.29
2007-02-20  0.50  0.67
```

#### first and last

You can follow your initial logic by adding a further [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and slicing the first and last column:

```
df.bfill(axis=1).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, [0,-1]].set_axis(['1st', '3rd'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
             1st   3rd
date                  
2007-02-15 -0.88  0.50
2007-02-16  0.50  0.29
2007-02-19 -0.84  0.29
2007-02-20  0.50  0.50
```

Another option with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(['first', 'last'])
```

Output:

```
            first  last
date                   
2007-02-15  -0.88  0.50
2007-02-16   0.50  0.29
2007-02-19  -0.84  0.29
2007-02-20   0.50  0.50
```

Comment: Thanks, but this finds the first and last non-blank. I need first and third

Answer (score 1):

You can do `sorted` then pick the value with columns number

```
out = df.transform(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull),1)
Out[51]: 
               0     1     2    3    4
date                                  
2007-02-15 -0.88  0.80  0.50  NaN  NaN
2007-02-16  0.50 -0.84  0.29  NaN  NaN
2007-02-19 -0.84  0.79  0.29  NaN  NaN
2007-02-20  0.50  0.50  0.67  0.2  0.5
#first = out[0]
```